# android button animation with sucess and fail statuses

Tags: android

I need to implement something like this (open like a gif file):
[image: GIF]

There is a way to create a simple animation:
[drawable-animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html)

But how to create an animation with states:

(1) initial animation -> (2) progress animation: while a network operation -> (3) success or fail animation status
?

Comment: For that may be you can use `ObjectAnimator` class.